# How can I summarize array's item greater, than 0, lower than 10

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to run a simple code, that summarize arrays item, greater, than 0, lower than 10.

can you, please look through my code - can't get, why it still summarize all entered numbers:

```
import sys

print ("Hello word")
data = sys.stdin.readline()
tokens = data.split()

for i in range(len(tokens)):
    tokens[i] = int(tokens[i])

for token in tokens:
    if (token > 0 & token < 10):
        b = sum(tokens)
    else:
        print("err")



print (b)
```

Comment: why are you using `stdin.readline()`? what is `data`?  Please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: do you wanna raise an error in case one of the condition is not filled or simply sum filtered list?

Comment: any reason to use `sys.stdin.readline()` instead of the build-in [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)??

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `and` not `&`, `&` is [bitwise](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) and:

**x & y**

Does a "bitwise and". Each bit of the output is 1 if the corresponding bit of x AND of y is 1, otherwise it's 0.

What you should be doing:

```
for token in tokens:
    if token > 0 and token < 10:
      ....
```

The difference:

```
In [8]: token = 100

In [9]: token > 0 & token < 10
Out[9]: True

In [10]: token > 0 and token < 10
Out[10]: False

 # would work but don't do it
In [11]: (token > 0)  & (token < 10)
Out[1]: True
```

You cam also simplify it further with chained comparison:

```
for token in tokens:
    if 0 < token < 10:
```

If you are trying to get the sum of all in the range 0-10, you can just use sum and filter with the if after mapping to `int`:

```
data = sys.stdin.readline()
tokens = data.split()

print (sum(token for token in map(int, tokens.split(",")) if 0 < token < 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also while `sum`ming, `filter` those integers which are outside your desired range:

```
>>> tokens = ['1','2','3','5','10','11', '4', '6']
>>> sum(filter(lambda x: 0 < x < 10, map(int, (x for x in tokens))))
21
```

And like it's been mentioned in the previous answers, you were using the bitwise and `&` instead of the logical one `and`

Another better approach, is to do it with generator expression avoiding using any of `filter`, 'lambda' and `map`:

```
>>> sum(i for i in (int(x) for x in tokens) if 0 < i < 10)
```

Profiling both methods, lead to:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('sum(filter(lambda x: 0<x<10, map(int, (x for x in tokens))))', "tokens = ['1','2','3','5','10','11', '4', '6']", number=10**5)
0.2696745040011592
>>> 
>>> timeit.timeit('sum(i for i in(int(x) for x in tokens) if 0 < i < 10)', "tokens = ['1','2','3','5','10','11', '4', '6']", number=10**5)
0.24827877001371235
```

As one can notice, the generator expression is faster in this case.

Comment: Slightly over kill - you can avoid `filter` and `lambda` and `map` and make it using just gen-exps with `sum` - which'll have exactly the same behaviour in 2.x as and 3.x - eg: `sum(i for i in (int(t) for t in tokens) if 0 < i < 10)`

Answer (score -1):

Each time one token is bigger than 0 and smaller than 10 you set b equal to the sum of all tokens (independent of the value of these). You should either:

- create a "filtered" list and sum that one
- write the "sum" yourself

The second approach would look like the following:

```
b = 0
for token in tokens:
    if (token > 0 & token < 10):
        b = b + token
    else:
        print("err")
```

That said, your code isn't very "pythonic" (that means it does not use the capabilities python gives you do deal with problems). A for loop can not only count an integer variable up (like a java `for (int i=0; i<10; i++)` loop) but iterate over any iterable (comparable to a `for (Object : iterable)` loop in java). See the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) for more information.

Later you might want to use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of a for loop in this case.